# Add class on hover for children in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, jquery-hover

I have a page which will have a series of "tile" divs, each of which will have one one or more child divs.

I want to, when rolling over the parent div, change the class of it and all divs to a hover state.

I can easily get the parent div working, but can't get the child: [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/xg8jg/1/)

```
$('.tile').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).addClass("hover");
                $(this).find('.inner').addClass("hover");
              },
              function () {
                $(this).removeClass("hover");
                $(this).find('.inner').removeClass("hover");
              }
        )
```

All the examples I see using "find" use a NAMED parent; but I just need to use the children of whichever current parent is being hovered over ($this).

EDIT/UPDATE:

Part of my problem is that inside the div there's an image button.  That button is supposed to have its OWN rollover. See image from the designer below.  I can get the first combination -- everything cyan and the white plus button... but with CSS I can't affect the PARENTS of the lus button, can I?

[image]

Comment: Are there are two different states for these .tiles- one for before the tile is added to user's destinations (grey button, whitish background) and one for after it is added (blue button, whitish background)?

Comment: Not clear, but from these specs they want the lower rollover when you hover over the tile, and then the top right rollover when you hover over the button itself. [This might work](http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/Kpbv4/)

Comment: This is one of those "looks pretty in comps, makes no sense when you use it" type of static designs :) Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of scripting this, try using CSS pseudo-class :hover on ALL your hovered elements like:

```
    .tile {
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: yellow;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    .tile:hover {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
    .inner {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: goldenrod;
    }

    .tile:hover .inner{
        background-color:#369;
    }

    .tile:hover button{
        color:#ff0000;
    }
    .tile:hover button:hover{
        color:#00ff00;
    }
```

​
No script, no worries :)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/67tCr/

Comment: Upvote for CSS > JS. Performance will ALWAYS be better with CSS.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I was unaware (for some reason) that the hover change to the child would be localized to the tile in question.  This is great.

Comment: Multi-stage hover is possible!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine...you just need to re-order your css rules:

```
.tile {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 20px;
}

.inner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: goldenrod;
}

.hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xg8jg/2/)

Or you can be more specific

```
.hover, .inner.hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the 'children' function:

```
$(".title").hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("hover");
  $(this).children(".inner").addClass("hover");
},function(){
  $(this).removeClass("hover");
  $(this).children(".inner").removeClass("hover");
});
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ckaufman/qXU7R/1/